# Habilitar solo fechas deseadas en calendario datepicker

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, jquery-ui

estoy implementando un calendario datepicker para un proyecto de un sistema de turnos de profesionales, dicho profesional tiene una tabla donde se le configura la agenda, que cuanta con los campo Id, fecha_ini, fecha_fin, hora_ini, hora_fin, intervalo, dia (lunes, martes,miercoles, etc) que logro con esto generar un array de los dias, fechas que el profesional tendria agenda habilitada para poder cargarle turnos, el array me lo genera el codigo PHp desde mysql, lo que no logro hacer es cuando realizo la peticion de un profesional me mustre en un datepicker esa "agenda" osea los dias habilitados para asignar turno en el calendario, y que los demas por supuesto me los desabilite.

Gracias.

```
HtmL
<div id="calendario"></div>
```

```
turnero.js

var= diashabiles ["07-01-2019","14-01-2019","21-01-2019","28-01-2019","04-02-2019","11-02-2019","18-02-2019","25-02-2019","04-03-2019","11-03-2019","18-03-2019","25-03-2019","01-04-2019","08-04-2019","15-04-2019","22-04-2019","29-04-2019","06-05-2019","13-05-2019","20-05-2019","27-05-2019","03-06-2019","10-06-2019","17-06-2019","24-06-2019","01-07-2019","08-07-2019","15-07-2019","22-07-2019","29-07-2019","05-08-2019","12-08-2019","19-08-2019","26-08-2019","02-09-2019","09-09-2019","16-09-2019","23-09-2019","30-09-2019","07-10-2019","14-10-2019","21-10-2019","28-10-2019","04-11-2019","11-11-2019","18-11-2019","25-11-2019","02-12-2019","09-12-2019","16-12-2019","23-12-2019","30-12-2019","03-09-2019","10-09-2019","17-09-2019","24-09-2019","05-08-2019","12-08-2019","19-08-2019","26-08-2019","02-09-2019","09-09-2019","16-09-2019","23-09-2019"];
//la siguiente funcion al sera llamada desde otra funcion

function mostrarcalendario(flag)
{
    if (flag)
    {   
        $(function() {

            $('#calendario').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
            });
        });
    }else{
      $("#calendario").show();
    }  
}

function available(date) {

  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, diashabiles) != -1) {
    return [true, "","Available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
  }
}
```

Me habilita alguna fechas pero otras no. ej: 04/11/2019

Comment: Adjunta el código que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte.

Comment: hay alguna que pueda adjuntar los archivos correspondientes?

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta usando este link [edit] para copiar el añadir el codigo a tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias, ahi lo pude cargar en al pregunta.